# Why is the output 2020?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
   int data;
public:
   Foo(int d = 0) {
      data = d;
   }

   ~Foo() {
      cout << data;
   }
};

int main() {
   Foo a;
   a = 20;
   return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is 2020. I think what happens is, a temporary object a is created. Once the assignment operator is used to assign a the value of 20, the destructor is called and a 20 is printed. Then the main function reaches the return and the destructor is called a second time, printing 20 again.

Am I right?

Comment: Your understanding seems to be correct.

Comment: Spot on! You've figured it out.

Comment: Your post is also an illustration that if you are to override the copy constructor (you didn't do it, but just to illustrate the point), to realize that the compiler itself will call the copy constructor without you even aware of it being called.  Too many new programmers think that whatever they write in the copy constructor is isolated and will only be called when they want the copy constructor to be called, thus code all sorts of crazy things going on within the copy constructor.

Comment: hint: you don't have an `operator=` so what does `=` in `a = 20;` do?

Comment: Achievement unlocked: "C++ Apprentice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.
Actually modify your code as follows can show the logic of the code more clearly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
   int data;
public:
   Foo(int d = 0) {
      cout << "call constructor!" << endl;
      data = d;
   }

   ~Foo() {
      cout << data << endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   Foo a; // Foo::Foo(int d = 0) is called which yields the first line of output
   a = 20; // is equal to follows
   
   // 1. a temporary object is constructed which yields the second line of output
   Foo tmp(20);
   // 2. since you do not provide operator= member function,
   // the default one is generated the compiler
   // and a member-wise copy is performed
   a.operator=(&tmp);  
   // after this copy assignment, a.data == 20
   // 3. tmp is destroyed which yields the third line of output
   tmp.~Foo();
   // 4. right before the program exits, a is destroyed which yields the last line of output
   a.~Foo();

   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> call constructor!
>
> call constructor!
>
> 20
>
> 20